# set display to none if string is not translated

Tags: django, internationalization, django-i18n

I am writing a translation program and I am trying to implement a functionality where, If the translation string in the .po file is empty ( msgstr "" ) the parent elements visibility will be set to none.
As an example, if I have this template code:

```
 {% language target_language %}
  <td><p> {% translate Hello %} </p></td>
 {% endlanguage %}
```

If the target languages po file should look like this:

```
 #: translation/forms.py:10
 
 msgid "Hello"
 msgstr ""
```

then I would like to set:

```
 {% language target_language %}
  <td style="display: none"><p> {% translate Hello %} </p></td>
 {% endlanguage %}
```

How could I go about implementing this? I have worked myself through the Django internationalization but haven't found anything to point me in the right direction. I'm using Django 3.1 and Python 3.8.

Best Regards
Max

Comment: not sure if `with` works with other tags but give it a try: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't see how that would help me in this case.